# How to change installation folder of large applications?

Tags: directory, disk-usage

I'd like to install Ubuntu to my little SSD disk, and some core applications like Firefox, Inkscape, and Office, but install all other applications with `apt` to my big hard disk and my home folder (stuff like games, virtual instruments, documents, Haskell/Dart/Rust/npm frameoworks).

How can I do this easily please at install time, or later?

All the answers on here just seem to be people judgmentally saying "you don't need to do that" from a time before SSDs existed I think.

Surely there's a good way in 2022 to accomplish this common task in Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you sure you want to install Ubuntu Core 22?   That's a *specialist server* release and not a desktop release (desktop releases are all *year.month* in format; not the specialist *year* format products).  If instead of 22, you mean 22.04 - you can use *Something else* and setup the disks however you like  (apps go to directories; you can decide what disk those directories are on though); but be aware 22 & 22.04 are different products (22.04 came out in 2022-April thus 22.04; the specialist 22 server system didn't come out till 2022-July but the month isn't used for *specialist* releases)

Comment: Sorry, where did I say Core? Ubuntu 22 desktop is what I use.

Comment: Ok, thanks, changed it.

Comment: There is no way to arbitrarily select the installation location. You can move /usr and /home to the HDD, and than, all programms and personal files will be there.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever, how do I do this please?

Comment: There's no *easy* way to do it, only parts of it can be setup at install time, and there is no single magical shell incantation. It requires you to understand how applications are installed into the filesystem, how to determine how much storage space each application consumes, how to use the `mount` command and `/etc/fstab` file, and how to maintain your setup. It's a lot of work. It's NOT a common task in Linux. The entire OS is Open Source; if folks want to add this feature, their contributions will be welcome.

Comment: You can search for "install ubuntu separate home". The steps for `/usr`, where most programms are installed, are the same.

Comment: Thanks @user535733, if it is not a common task, then what do people do when installing large applications in modern small disks? Artists and musicians don't use Linux, so there aren't large videos and virtual instruments to keep, but surely programmers can have huge amounts of software to install? Do they all just have on massive main disk?

Comment: Not all "modern disks" are small, quite the opposite. 1TB+ SSD are effordable, and HDDs can be 20TB+. Perhaps you should buy a large SSD.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thank you, this is a great solution. I haven't checked prices since I bought about five years ago and a 500GB SSD is affordable in my country now. That should be all I need if I just change the Wine install path to my HD, and move my personal files out of Home manually to the HD too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automated APT package management system expect a standard system file structure, **which you may not change** (unless you are prepared to implement your own system, or prefer to compile manually.

Even a little SSD disk of 30 GB (you did not specify the size) should be adequate to host the system files of a Linux system. Your first option therefore is to see whether you have user data on that SSD (home directories, other data elsewhere) that can be moved.

In the unlikely case that you *really* have a *very small* SSD, you still can move system directories rather simply to another data volume by replacing the original directories by a symbolic link pointing to the new location.

- Move the system directory, preserving all file attributes and permissions
- Place a symbolic link in place that points to the new location

`/opt` is a very good candidate to move first. It is the directory where manually installed binaries are placed.

`/tmp`  and `/var/tmp` will benefit from moving out to a larger storage volume

If you use containerized applications, e.g. snap or flatpak, moving out `/var/lib/snapd` or `/var/lib/flatpak` will gain gigabytes of space.

Even specific directories of specific applications can be moved out - the system will find them through the symbolic links.

Needles to say is that these interventions require that the system is not running. Do that, therefore, from a live session.

Comment: Thank you very much! When you say 'move the directory', do you mean I `mv -r` all the contents to a new folder? And then what command symbolic points the old `/opt` to the new `sdb/opt_bigger`?

Comment: `mv /opt /mountpoint/sdb/opt_bigger` would move the directory (and all contents), preserving file attributes. `ln -s /mountpoint/sdb/opt_bigger /opt` would make a symlink `/opt` pointing to  `/mountpoint/sdb/opt_bigger`. If `opt_bigger` already exists, the target will be  `/mountpoint/sdb/opt_bigger/opt` instead